# Should I do Win Application?

Tags: asp.net, windows, web-applications, forms, winapp

It's a question comes to my mind all the time and So i would like to share , And know you mature programmers opinion's .

Unfortunately i spent some years of my life doing Graphic (web) and suddenly i quite and start Web Programming ( because i found myself more interested in programming and because i  had a base knowledge about web ) . And now It's more than a year i'm doing .Net (ASP.NET WebApp)programming .
During these time , I never even create a Windows Form Application template in VS .

When i take a look at  profiles of sophisticated programmers , I see they all know a lot of technologies and I feel so bad .

Do you think Should i learn and do Win App Programming ? Because there are enough (a lot)  different things out there in Web world that i can't catch up .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Only you can answer this question.

Comment: I really want to know , Do i regret in future if don't do win Programing , And Because there are a lot mature programmer in this community , So they answer will direct me in correct way , I really i don't understand why you voted this to be closed !?

Comment: Really, you can get exposure to many technologies but not know them well (many of us have), or you can focus on one thing and be the expert.  I will admit having a broader knowledge opens your mind, but if it deviates from your goals it may not be the way to go. (Don't bite off more than you can chew).  So to add to Michael, find out what your goals off and pursue them the best way possible.

Comment: If you have this doubt, try some simple projects just to know what it is like. You'll see if you like it and if it's worth regarding your business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you've probably spent more time over the past year doing web development is because there is more work in that arena.  The TCO (total cost of ownership) to organizations offering web-based access to an application vs. fat client distribution is hard to argue with.  There are relatively rare cases (hardware interface, disconnected solutions, OS plug-ins, etc.) where it still makes sense to write applications for the desktop, but in most cases the demand for your skills will remain on the web because that's where the savvy people paying for all this work are spending their money.

Rather than turn toward WinForms development take a look at sharpening your skills for the cloud.  Amazon Web Services, RackSpace, Microsoft Azure, VMWare, IBM and others are all getting into that space and it's only going to grow, and quickly.  Right now there aren't a lot of people who have much experience in this space because it is relatively new.  You can more easily differentiate yourself if you teach yourself some skills in this area while it's still new.

If you aren't the teach-yourself type consider looking at something closer to what you already are comfortable with and check out ASP.net MVC or brushing up on jQuery.  There are better online references and even some books to help with each of those.

Good luck / keep enjoying what you're doing and the experience will come!

Answer (score 3):

The WinForms programming model is quite similar to that of WebForms. Why not give it a try and see if you like it? Investing those few minutes it takes to create a project from that template and poking around I would say are minutes well spent. After all, it is within the samme .Net Framework. What .Net knowledge you have already and any new knowledge you gain will benefit you when developing apps in both WinForms and WebForms.

**Update:** when you see how easy WinForms development is, I would advice (as @Richard Hein also suggests) moving on to XAML-based apps. WinForms is superseded by WPF and Silverlight.

Comment: The reason is , because  i'm dealing with a lot of technologies in web world at the moment ie : jQuery , Silverlight , Ajax , .....
And if i enter in win form i will gear with a lot of different technlogies like "WPF , WCF , .... that i don't think i could catch up

Comment: The WinForms application model has nothing to do with WPF. And you can easily create WinForms apps that never use WCF, unless you need to talk to web services.
But: do you already know Silverlight? Why not then venture the WPF way? WPF is to Silverlight as WinForms is to WebForms.

Comment: @Mostafa Windows Forms (WinForms) is different from WPF. WPF is the newer model.

Answer (score 2):

I'd skip ahead and learn WPF application development and Silverlight development, because it will benefit you more to do that than Windows Forms.  Also XAML based applications are more similar to web development than Windows Forms.  Any investment in learning Windows Forms will not be as valuable, going forward.